# Error Angular is undefined. While injecting directives and other files in the chrome extension using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-chrome

I am working on a Chrome Extension that will inject the directives into any live form as per the configuration done by the Admin. These directive are the Custom Directives that I want to inject while rendering is still on. These directive needs angular.min.js file as the dependency so i am using the following code to do so.

```
$jz('html').attr({'ng-app':'jazzApp','ng-csp':''});
$jz('<script type="text/javascript"  src="'+myApp.chromeExtUrl+'js/jquery.min.js"></script>').appendTo('head');
$jz('<script type="text/javascript"  src="'+myApp.chromeExtUrl+'js/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>').appendTo('head');
$jz('<script type="text/javascript" src="'+myApp.chromeExtUrl+'js/app.js"></script>').appendTo('head');
$jz('<script type="text/javascript" src="'+ myApp.chromeExtUrl+'js/directives/autocompleteField.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="'+ myApp.chromeExtUrl+'js/directives/dateField.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="'+ myApp.chromeExtUrl+'js/directives/numberField.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="'+ myApp.chromeExtUrl+'js/directives/validateField.js"></script>').appendTo('head');
```

---

My angular is taking too much time to inject in the meantime i get an error in the console

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined(anonymous function) @app.js?_=1435743495373:3 angular.js:36
Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$injector/nomod?p0=jazzApp(anonymous function) @ angular.js:36
```

Can i get a solution to optimize the angular.min.js loading?

Comment: Maybe you are getting this error because you haven't added ng-app in your webpage.

Comment: @chiragchavda.ks hi i am adding ng-app using the following code  $jz('html').attr({'ng-app':'jazzApp','ng-csp':''});